# How to disable only Force stop button android

Tags: android, device-admin

How to disable only Force stop button not Uninstall button in android. I'm using below link code but it disabling both uninstall and force stop button

http://prashantandroid.blogspot.in/2013/07/disable-force-stop-in-manage.html

Comment: refer [this](https://github.com/prashantadesara/DeviceAdminDemo) may help

Comment: same code im using it disabling both uninstall and force stop button

Answer (score 1):

to prevent the uninstall you need to add an administration service type to turn off the screen